# How does ASP.NET Core determine MIME types and apply different middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I use ASP.NET Core MVC and .NET Core 2.0.

I have some static files, they have different file types, JPEG, PNG, BMP ...

I would like to apply different middleware according to different file types.

Such as PNG file I will use ImageCompressMiddleware, BMP file I will use ImageConvertMiddleware.

How does ASP.NET Core determine MIME types and apply different middleware?

Or according to the file extension.

Answer (score 13):

Create a FileExtensionContentTypeProvider object in configure section and fill or remove Mapping for each MIME Type as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Set up custom content types -associating file extension to MIME type
    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    // Add new mappings
    provider.Mappings[".myapp"] = "application/x-msdownload";
    provider.Mappings[".htm3"] = "text/html";
    provider.Mappings[".image"] = "image/png";
    // Replace an existing mapping
    provider.Mappings[".rtf"] = "application/x-msdownload";
    // Remove MP4 videos.
    provider.Mappings.Remove(".mp4");

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot", "images")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/MyImages"),
        ContentTypeProvider = provider
    });
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Go to this link for more information:
[microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files)

Answer (score 3):

The static files middleware basically has [a very long list of explicit file extension to MIME type mappings](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v2.2.1/src/Middleware/StaticFiles/src/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs). So the MIME type detection is solely based on the file extension.

There is not really a clear way to hook into the middleware *after* the MIME type has been detected but before the static files middleware actually runs. However, you can use the [`StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileoptions.onprepareresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.2) callback to hook into it to for example modify headers. Whether that’s enough for you depends on what you are trying to do.

If you want to do a more sophisticated handling, possibly replacing the static files middleware, you would need to run your own implementation of the MIME type detection.