# Angular 8 inside of ASP Net Core was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular8, asp-net-core-spa-services

I'm trying to set up my own angular 8 app to be served from inside of an ASP.Net Core website (so I don't have to deal with cross-site-scripting or having two (sub-)domains, or issues with authentication.

I've built a web app in VS Code, and compiled it to the folder `wwwroot/app` in my asp net core 3.0 project (I can run the app using `ng serve` just fine).

I have added this in `Startup` `ConfigureServices()`

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
 configuration.RootPath = "wwwroot/app";
});
```

And have this in `Configure()`

```
app.UseSpa(spa => {});
```

This partly works. When I load up the asp.net project the angular app starts to load. But the console is filled with (one for every file specified in the generated index.html):

> Loading module from “https://localhost:5001/runtime.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
>
> Loading module from “https://localhost:5001/polyfills.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
>
> Loading module from “https://localhost:5001/vendor.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
>
> Loading module from “https://localhost:5001/styles.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
>
> Loading module from “https://localhost:5001/main.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

As far as I understand it the angular-cli did not include mime-types on the files when they were *"compiled"*, and thus the web browser does not care for them.

The angular people don't think this is an error/bug and have closed an issue relating to this (although this behavior is different to how Angular 7 did this): https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10325

Reading this question [How to add Mime Types in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770084/how-to-add-mime-types-in-asp-net-core) I figured I might be able to do something like this:

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".js"] = "application/javascript";
provider.Mappings[".html"] = "text/html";
provider.Mappings[".ico"] = "image/vnd.microsoft.icon";


var statFilesOptions = new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
};

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = statFilesOptions;
});
```

To add the mime/types to the files. But this did nothing at all.

Any other ideas on how this can be fixed **without editing generated** files?

Comment: For me happened cause I forgot to inherit the API controller from the ControllerBase class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was not at all what I expected it to be. The asp.net core app was actually returning the `index.html` file for all requests as it could not find the javascript files. Hence the error was actually correct.

Changing the `<base href="/">` in `index.html` to `<base href="/app/">` solved this partially as it now knew to look for the files in the app folder I placed them in, but made reloads stop working (as the url was wrong).

My solution was to set the output folder of the angular build as the root of `/wwwroot/` in the asp net core project. Now it all works.

Comment: I was doing this for a few hours with no lock. Finally found out that the trailing `/` in `/app/` is really important. So I leave this here for everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Emad comment is absolutely right. I spent 2 days altering Program.cs on a .net 6 Host for an Angular Webpack Mfe with remoteEntry.js:

> Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
> main.js:1 polyfills.js:1

It was the trailing / in index.html. It should have been only /app.

Thank you Emad !

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32247057)