# Add Mime Types in ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, mime-types, blazor-client-side

I'm working with an app made from the Blazor Client template and am trying to add 2 mime types.  I have found [the answer how to do this in earlier versions of .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770084/how-to-add-mime-types-in-asp-net-core) but it does not work with the newer template I am using.  The old solution relies on Startup.cs having a Configure method with the signature: `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)` but the new template uses the signature: `public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder componentsApplicationBuilder)`

How do I add mime types with this new configure method?

Comment: It's not an old vs. new situation. Previously Blazor Webassembly had *no* startup, and now it does. The code you're looking at is for ASP.NET Core and Blazor Server-side, since it's still an ASP.NET Core app.

Comment: Ultimately, Blazor Webassembly has to be *served* somehow. Be it an ASP.NET Core app, directly via a web server like nginx, or even just throwing it up on some publically accessible blob storage. In either of those cases, the mime types are controlled by the host, not your Blazor Webassembly app itself.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Blazor Apps can self host, and dynamically add mime types to IIS.  The Blazor Client template I am using has a wwwroot folder from which it serves static files.  However, it won't serve static files that it can't map to a mime type.  There has to be a way to allow this.