# href download only works for some extensions

Tags: html, asp.net-core, href

I am building an ASP.NET Core web application where I would like to serve a file with .L5X extension as a download link. The file is a plain text, but has application specific extension.
This is what I have in the view:

```
<a href="/data/downloads/test.l5x" type="text/xml" id="downloadLink" download>download</a>
```

The issue I am facing is that the href link won't work and I get "Failed - No File" error all the time.

The strange thing is, when I changed the extension to txt or docx (both in the actual file and the href), the download would work fine.
For eaxmple, below href would work:

```
 <a href="/data/downloads/test.txt" type="text/xml" id="downloadLink" download>download</a>
```

I searched the web, but couldn't find answer - help?

Comment: I don't think the error is due to that, but for .l5x use `type="application/octet-stream"` instead of text/xml

Comment: thanks for your reply - i tried your suggestion, but it's not it. I changed to use the type "application/octet-stream" and still show "Failed - No File".

Comment: this is what I'm getting: https://ibb.co/VNJd09m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you host application in IIS on windows server. If that's the case, you should add a mime type matching your extension in IIS. Open IIS, Select your root server name and then from the modules list, double click Mime Type and then from right side panel click Add. From this windows, you can enter your extension with type. Such as File Name Extension field should be .l5x and MIME Type would be 'application/octet-stream'. This will simply solve your problem.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that, but I still get the same error. It looks like the application doesn't use IIS, when I launched straight from VS, it runs some kind of contained hosting service like shown in https://ibb.co/bJxzXdb

Comment: I think this has pointed me to the right direction. I found that I needed to register mime type in asp.net core in different way as described in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770084/how-to-add-mime-types-in-asp-net-core